# FileLock to prevent deletion of a file but I can't open it

Tags: java, filelock

I'm using a FileLock to prevent the deletion of a .zip file but I can't open it. So I'm trying to find something to block the file but be able to open it.
There is my code :

```
File file = new File(myfile);

FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();
FileLock lock = channel.lock();

try {
    lock = channel.tryLock();
} catch (OverlappingFileLockException e) {}
```

Thanks !

Comment: what about using `Channels.newChannel(in)` ?

Comment: like that ? : `FileChannel channel = (FileChannel) Channels.newChannel(in);`

it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

OH no ok `Channels.newChannel(in)` works perfectly